# unable to access post request params in golang

Tags: javascript, jquery, go

I am trying to access post params in golang which are sent via jquery ajax. Maybe I am missing something obvious. Here are my code snippets

```
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var jsn = {
            vvv = $("#textinput").val();   
        };
        console.log(jsn);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async : true,
        //enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "/homepage",
        data: jsn,
        processData: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
    }).done(function(response){
        $("#resultdiv").html(response);
    });
});
```

here is my golang code:

```
 func MainConversion(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     r.ParseForm()    
        text := r.FormValue("vvv")
        fmt.Fprint(w, string(text))
        return
    })
```

I have tried f.formValue(), r.Form.get() . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You've sent your request with a JSON body, but `ParseForm` on an `*http.Request` does not handle JSON. You need to read the body of the request and parse it as JSON, or don't send your body as JSON.

```
func MainConversion(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var body = make(map[string]string)
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&body); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    text := body["vvv"]
    w.Write([]byte(text))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS snippet contains syntax errors, so I assume no request reaches your golang API.

```
var jsn = {
    vvv = $("#textinput").val();   
};
```

should be:

```
var jsn = {
    vvv : $("#textinput").val()
};
```

Comment: yes but even after updating it still doesn't reach golang. I'm unable to figure out the mistake i'm doing